# Why do we have scope resolution operator right after equal sign?

Tags: c++, oop, struct

This is a C++ Code. I cannot understand what does a scope resolution operator do right after equal sign

```
const tflite::Model* model = ::tflite::GetModel(g_model);
```

Comment: The leading `::` means "at the top level namespace".  The top level namespace, or root namespace, doesn't have a name itself.  It's not very commonly used in C++ code, and is discouraged to use generally (because it makes name resolution fixed), but do use it when you have to (because you need fixed namespace resolution).

Comment: @Ali Aqdas It looks like just a bad code. At least the declaration should ;look like  const  ::tflite::Model* model = ::tflite::GetModel(g_model);